# how to start a media player once stopped

Tags: android

I have added two buttons to my app, one to play and one to start. As soon as i start the app the songs starts playing automatically. when i press on stops it stops but when i press on play it doesnt starts again

To stop I have used `mediaplayer.stop()` which is working fine

To start I have used

```
mediaplayer.start()
```

which is not working

According to flow diagram its given we need to use

```
prepare()
```

and then

```
OnPreparedListener.onPrepared()
```

and then

```
start()
```

I don't know how to use these functions. Please help me

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Try my below solution and let me know whether it is working or not?

Answer (score 3):

Don't call `stop()` for stopping the mediaplayer use `reset()` instead. I dont have good reason for that. But, it'll work for sure.

```
 // for stopping it call below statement 
    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
    mediaPlayer.reset();

    //for playing it again 
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

For starting media player again use following code.

```
if (mediaplayer != null) {
        mediaplayer.start();
        }
```

and one more thing, instead of using

```
mediaplayer.stop()
```

use

```
mediaplayer.pause();
```

so it will pause the current song instead of stop.

Just check the condition whether it is null or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code  on Play `Button`

```
mp.reset();
mp.setDataSource(song path);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();

mp.setDataSource(song path); not necessary if you playing same sound again
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaPlayer mp;


@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);
        btnsound=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play_sound);
        btnstopsound=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop_sound);
        mp=new MediaPlayer();

        btnsound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                try {
                    mp.setDataSource(Sound);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    mp.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                    mp.start();
                    mp.setLooping(true);


                }



        });

        btnstopsound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.setLooping(false);
                mp.stop();
            }
        });




    }
```